# Устройство хранения видео на видеохостингах

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Интересует такой вопрос — как устроено хранение видео на видеохостингах? Например, заливаю я видео на сайт, информация о нем записывается в базу данных, в том числе название видео, после чего, когда я открываю видео для просмотра, информация берется из БД, и видео находится в архиве сайта по названию?

Comment: По хешу, да ещё и с префиксом или в поддиректории с уникальным названием

Надеюсь вы не подразумеваете под архивом сжатый архив

Comment: @Gedweb, то есть, необходимо, когда юзер заливает файл на сервер, переименовывать его, например, в md5(название) и записывать название в таком виде? Под архивом подразумеваю просто директорию с файлами. (Файловый архив)

Comment: @Fishy прочитайте про CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ваше представление о пороге манипулирования данными сводится к банальному представлению о софтовой связке сервера, типа Apache/Denwer, с базой, типа MySQL, причем установленном всём этом на простой машине типа PC, ну или на крайний случай, на некоем мигающем лампочками "сервере", который не похож на тот компьютер, который у вас под столом.

`Здесь и далее пишу относительно, так как стандартной схемы не бывает.`

В первую очередь, для манипулирования данными, развертывается аппаратное решение, масштабируемое и заточенное под конкретные цели. Скорость и реализацию *методов доступа* к данным берет на себя именно аппаратно-программное решение, которое непосредственно к вебсерверу не имеет прямого отношения. Скажем так, обязанности распределяются - реализация проекта, которая под вебсервером, даже и не знает, на какой платформе развернуты данные (имеется ввиду платформа а/п решения), т.е. знает, какие данные нужны, но не отвечает за то, чтобы эти данные быстро и легко находились бы среди десятков миллионов единиц некоего контента - за это отвечает, как я уже говорил, аппаратно-программное решение. Таких платформ (решений) множество - они есть у ведущих корпораций - IBM, HP, EMC и т.д. Кластеры, хранилища данных, массивы дисков, системы оптимизации и индексации, кеширования - эти и многие понятия свойственны этим системам, которые обеспечивают хранение данных в том оптимальном виде, чтобы обеспечивать максимальную скорость, надежность, избыточность (redundancy) и прочее. Такого рода платформы, как правило, предоставляют зачастую и свои API, которые можно и полезно использовать в процессе построения веб-аппликаций. Этих всех понятий нет в настольном компьютере или единичном "сервере", поэтому полезно будет почитать обо всем этом.

Есть такое понятие, как архитектура приложений. Отвечая на ваш вопрос напрямую, то вряд ли некий большой видеохостинг *вот именно так банально* хранит данные, как вы себе представляете - по принципу "хэш имени файла в поле таблицы и всего делов". Программистами и архитекторами разрабатываются алгоритмы, позволяющие по некоторым или многим критериям *направлять* данные в определенные, скажем, таблицы (банальный пример: хотя бы направлять запись о файле в нужную *таблицу* по первой букве названия самого файла - это как самый простой пример для вас, показывающий, как оптимизировать массу файлов, - т.е. один из шагов. Само собой критериев может быть и больше - сортировка по размерам файлов, по имени автора, типу видео (юмор, 18+, мультики), страны загрузки и т.д. - для дистрибуции хранения и для последующего *легкого* поиска тем самым скриптом, который *знает* о такой схеме дистрибуции контента -  вы поняли о чем я), строятся структуры баз данных с переплетенными данными в таблицах, пишутся процедуры, триггеры  и прочее. А аппаратно-программное решение гарантирует скорость поиска/записи/считывания тех данных, за которым обращается вебсервер, скажем, в базу данных.

Изложил очень кратко, но с тем замыслом, что автор, не имеющий пока представления о такого рода решениях, заинтересовавшись, всегда найдет подробное описание того, о чем я написал.

Comment: ну да как пример - две начальные цифры хэша указывают на ip в сетке /24 :)